# Remove duplicate main - submenu in admin?

Tags: admin-menu

When I use `add_menu_page` & `add_submenu_page` to add menu items,

```
add_menu_page( 'Forms', 'Forms', 'administrator', 'forms', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Job Applications', 'Job Applications', 'administrator', 'job-applications', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Quote Requests', 'Quote Requests', 'administrator', 'quote-req', 'forms_req_menupage_cb' );
add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Contact', 'Contact', 'administrator', 'contact', 'forms_contact_menupage_cb' );
```

I will get something like

- Forms

  - Forms
  - Job Applications
  - Quote Requests
  - Contacts

Is it possible to create it such that it becomes

- Forms

  - Job Applications
  - Quote Requests
  - Contacts

In other words Forms will link to Job Applications and I dont want the extra Forms submenu item

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hi **@JM at Work:**

Yes, it is unfortunately that the submenu page is added for every menu page. It would be nice [if there were an option but alas, there currently is not](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17324#comment:21).

To remove the submenu page option in WordPress 3.1 or great use `remove_submenu_page()` with code like this in your theme's `functions.php` file, or in a `.php` file of a plugin you might be writing:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'yoursite_admin_menu' );
function yoursite_admin_menu() {
  add_menu_page( 'Forms', 'Forms', 'administrator', 'forms', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
  add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Job Applications', 'Job Applications', 'administrator', 'job-applications', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
  add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Quote Requests', 'Quote Requests', 'administrator', 'quote-req', 'forms_req_menupage_cb' );
  add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Contact', 'Contact', 'administrator', 'contact', 'forms_contact_menupage_cb' );
  remove_submenu_page('forms','forms');
}
```

If you are still using WordPress 3.0 you have to `unset()` an element of the global variable `$submenu` like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'yoursite_admin_menu' );
function yoursite_admin_menu() {
  add_menu_page( 'Forms', 'Forms', 'administrator', 'forms', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
  add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Job Applications', 'Job Applications', 'administrator', 'job-applications', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
  add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Quote Requests', 'Quote Requests', 'administrator', 'quote-req', 'forms_req_menupage_cb' );
  add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Contact', 'Contact', 'administrator', 'contact', 'forms_contact_menupage_cb' );
  unset($GLOBALS['submenu']['forms'][0]);
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks...........  :)

Answer (score 3):

Assign the first submenu slug similar to the parent menu. In your case, replace 'job-applications' with the slug of the main menu 'forms'.

```
add_menu_page( 'Forms', 'Forms', 'administrator', 'forms', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Job Applications', 'Job Applications', 'administrator', 'forms', 'forms_job_menupage_cb' );
add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Quote Requests', 'Quote Requests', 'administrator', 'quote-req', 'forms_req_menupage_cb' );
add_submenu_page( 'forms', 'Contact', 'Contact', 'administrator', 'contact', 'forms_contact_menupage_cb' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add_submenu_page, then remove it (wp 4.0.1)

```
add_menu_page( 'Admin Tools', 'Admin Tools', 'manage_options','parent', '__return_null','', "70.23423" );
    // this 'hides' the extra.  actually, just makes the text nothing: ''  
    add_submenu_page( 'parent', '',     '', 'manage_options',   'parent',   '__return_null' );
    //ah, but this removes it completely (you need to add it, then remove it :/     
    remove_submenu_page('parent','parent');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *keeping* the extra menu item, becuase it's how all the other WP menus work. (I know that's not what you asked!...) The way the other top-level menus work is that they have different labels for the big menu title and the duplicate one below it (e.g. 'Users', 'All Users'; 'Tools', 'Available Tools'). I think it's good to stick with the same paradigm, so I usually rename the first submenu item like this:

```
<?php
add_menu_page( 'Plugin Name', 'Plugin Name', 'read', 'plugin-slug', $callback );
add_submenu_page( 'plugin-slug', 'Plugin Overview', 'Overview', 'read', 'plugin-slug', $callback );
```